# how to pass parameters to angular js file using gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp

Is there any way to pass config parameters like IP address or something using gulp?
I got something like gulp-load-params (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-params) but then how to pass parameters to js file?

Comment: Have you looked at [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant). This can be used to generate config values based on your environment which can then be injected into your controllers/services etc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any direct plugin for this but i have done the following:

1. Passed the parameter through cli to a particular task.
2. Replaced this parameter with the string in JS file using gulp-replace plugin.